# Oracle SQL - import dump and change data

Tags: oracle, plsql, datapump

Im trying to import a database from a dump into oracle, and once the import has completed, I'd like to make some changes to that data. What would be best way to accomplish this? The script below will import the dump file and remap the schema, but the job seems to fork and the changes try to run before the datapump completes. I am an Oracle novice, trying to run this on Oracle SE database. Thanks in advance for all advise/pointers.

```
begin

declare
h1 NUMBER;
h1_status varchar2(200);
begin
    h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'FULL', job_name => 'COPYBACK_IMPORT', version => 'COMPATIBLE');
    dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'COPYBACK.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
    dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'COPYBACK.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => 3);
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 0);
    dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'SOME_DB_DUMP.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE);
    dbms_datapump.metadata_remap(handle => h1, name => 'REMAP_TABLESPACE', old_value => 'SOME_TS', value => 'USERS');
    dbms_datapump.metadata_remap(handle => h1, name => 'REMAP_SCHEMA', old_value => 'SOMETHING', value => 'DBADMIN');
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1);
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC');
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'REUSE_DATAFILES', value => 0);
    dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION', value => 'REPLACE');
    dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0);
    dbms_datapump.wait_for_job(handle => h1, job_state => h1_status);
    dbms_datapump.detach(handle => h1);
end;
begin
    update DBADMIN.users set passwd = 'new_passwd', p_passwordencoding = 'plain' where p_uid = 'some_user';
    delete from DBADMIN.props where name='system.locked';
end;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the impdp from the OS instead of the package,  and then create a batch or sh file to execute the impdp with the parameters required (you may use a parameter file) and the if everything is ok, execute the update.